# Save scheduled tasks with powershell

Tags: powershell, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

I want to save my scheduled tasks using powershell.

I tried this:

```
$taskpath = "\mytasks\"   # all of my tasks are in this folder in Task Scheduler
$savefolder = "C:\tasks"  # where I want to save the xml files

Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath $taskpath | foreach { Export-ScheduledTask -TaskName $_.TaskName | Out-File (Join-Path $savefolder "$($_.TaskName).xml") }
```

Those paths exist.

But I get this error: `Export-ScheduledTask : The system cannot find the file specified.`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed to supply `TaskPath` into [`Export-ScheduledTask` cmdlet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/export-scheduledtask):

> ```
> -TaskPath [<String>]
>     Specifies the path for a scheduled task in Task Scheduler namespace. You
>      can use \ for the root folder. If you do not specify a path, the cmdlet
>      uses the root folder.
> ```

Use

```
$taskpath = "\mytasks\"   # all of my tasks are in this folder in Task Scheduler
$savefolder = "C:\tasks"  # where I want to save the xml files

Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath $taskpath | 
    Foreach-Object {
        $_.TaskName  ### debugging  output
        Export-ScheduledTask -TaskName $_.TaskName -TaskPath $_.TaskPath | 
                Out-File (Join-Path $savefolder "$($_.TaskName).xml") }
```

Instead of specifying particular `TaskName` and `TaskPath` parameters, you can pipe `InputObject` object obtained from `Get-ScheduledTask` into `Export-ScheduledTask` cmdlet as in the following code snippet:

```
Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath $taskpath | 
    Foreach-Object { $_ | Export-ScheduledTask | 
        Out-File (Join-Path $savefolder "$($_.TaskName).xml") }
```

Comment: Thanks that works! Do you mind explaining why my version fails but yours works? I don't understand because the only difference is you supply the object into the loop, but my one infers the current object. I would expect my way to work as well?

Comment: @LotPings I beg your pardon for my misunderstanding double negation in English (it's different in my native tongue).

Comment: Forget what he said, I understood you perfectly, and thanks for helping me! I hope one day I can speak PowerShell as well as you speak English :)

Comment: @Ionix In your version `Out-file` receives the xml data through the pipe no longer the ScheduledTask object, so there is no TaskName Property.

Comment: @JosefZ Sorry for being to picky on semantics. I'm no native English speaker myself and there was no harm intended. Found the fault also but was to slow to answer. One +1 is from me.

Comment: @LotPings thanks for helping me! For the record since we are all being honest, I'm not a native PowerShell speaker! :)